# Get AD user creation date in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm currently trying to get different info out of my AD.
but I'm having some issues with pulling the creation date of my users.

I get the correct date on some users, but on others I get null.

My current code looks like so:

```
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> rsc = srch.FindAll();
foreach (Principal found in rsc)
{    
    using (PrincipalContext ctx2 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "nianetas.local"))
    {
        UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, found.SamAccountName);
        DateTime creationTime;
        string creTime = found.GetProperty("whenCreated");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(creTime))
        {
            creationTime = DateTime.ParseExact(creTime,
                "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
        }
        else
        {
            creationTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

GetProperty function:

```
public static String GetProperty(this Principal principal, String property)
{
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
    if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
        return directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
    else
        return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: That probably means AD doesn't require that field to be set, and it's null for some users for some indeterminable reason.  There's nothing wrong with your application.

Comment: The thing is that all the users has this field when I look in 'Active Directory Users and Computers' and if I try to pull it from Powershell with the same user account.

Comment: So are you saying `creTime` is null or empty sometimes?

Comment: @rory.ap Yes that is the issue I'm having. I don't know if whenCreated is the right property to look for tho, it's just the only one I could find.

Comment: ...but regardless, `whenCreated` is *not* null when retrieved for the very same user with PowerShell or  users and computers?

Comment: Exactly.
I can look at User01 in Powershell or 'users and computers' and it got a whenCreated attribute, but when I look at User01 in C# (code above) it does not have a whenCreated attribute.

Comment: Users and computers doesn't show a "whenCreated"...it would have some display name which may actually be a different underlying field.  Try using ADSI edit; you can view the *actual* property values.

Comment: This is what I see https://i.imgur.com/6Q8IAM5.png so looking at this I would say the attribute is called whenCreated correct?

Comment: Do you use the same user to retrieve the data both in Powershell and in your code? Perhaps it's a permissions issue.

Comment: The exact same user @Tomer

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the [`RefreshCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/913td91k.aspx) method of the `DirectoryEntry` object with the `whenCreated` property. It looks like when using `GetUnderlyingObject()` not all of the `DirectoryEntry` properties are populated, because it is a heavy operation.

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
directoryEntry.RefreshCache(new string[] { "whenCreated" });
```

Comment: So something like this or did you mean something else?
https://gist.github.com/SonOfDiablo/4ac6f0d05c4fc27060c9f06142a8bec1

Comment: Edited with an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example, just tried it out ( https://gist.github.com/SonOfDiablo/8cb2d6d672b9f787104cbd9f01084f76 ) but it didn't change anything :/